# Unsupported browser error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I want to display GPS coordinates on Google Maps. For this purpose I chose web browser from the toolbox. But it show an error of unsupported browser. I tried updating my Internet Explorer. I also set Google Chrome as the Debugging Browser in Visual Studio but it didn't work.

This is the part of code where I am accessing the web browser.

```
try
{
    StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();

    queryaddress.Append("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=");

    if (lat != string.Empty)
    {
          queryaddress.Append(lat + "," + "+");
    }
    webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
}
```

Error

> You seem to be using an unsupported browser. Old browsers can put your
>   security at risk, are slow and don't work with newer Google Maps
>   features. To access Google Maps, you'll need to update to a modern
>   browser.

Someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Embedded Browser sontrol sends a IE7 Usr Agent header and uses the IE7 compatibility mode to render content. You can coax the control to use the installed IE version by setting a registry key.

Add a key to the registry, on your own machine, make sure you add both `YourApplication.exe` and `YourApplication.vshost.exe`.

> There are two different sets of keys for 32 bit and 64 bit applications.
>
> 64 bit or 32 bit only machine:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
> ```
>
> Value Key: `DWORD - YourApplication.exe`
>
> 32 bit on 64 bit machine:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
> ```
>
> Value Key: `DWORD YourApplication.exe`
>
> The value to set this key to is (taken from MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)) as decimal values:
>
> ```
> 11001 (0x2EDF)
> ```
>
> Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> ```
> 11000 (0x2AF8)
> ```
>
> Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
>
> ```
> 10001 (0x2AF7)
> ```
>
> Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> ```
> 10000 (0x2710)
> ```
>
> Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
>
> ```
> 9999 (0x270F)
> ```
>
> Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> ```
> 9000 (0x2328)
> ```
>
> Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
>
> ```
> 8888 (0x22B8)
> ```
>
> Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> ```
> 8000 (0x1F40)
> ```
>
> Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.
>
> 7000 (0x1B58) 
>   Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.

See also:

- https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: Thank you my problem got solved,made above changes in HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: In that case, please mark the answer as your answer by ticking the "v" sign in front of it.